# CSV without unique headers to list of dicts with unique keys

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a CSV file with headers on row 0. The headers are often unique but sometimes they are not, for "comments" in this example. For each of several comments, the header is "Comment".

The problem with my function that makes dicts from CSVs is that it only returns the last column of Comment.

```
def csv_to_list_with_dicts(csvfile):
    with open(csvfile) as f:
        list_of_issues = [{k: v for k, v in row.items()}
                          for row in csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True)]
    return list_of_issues
```

My CSV file columns are like this:

```
User;ID;Comment;Comment;Comment
```

If one of the headers is repeating, I need to add an index to make it unique (like Comment1;Comment2 without changing the CSV) in the dict or all comments included under just Comment.

Comment: Then don't use DictReader.  Just process the first line yourself and use the regular row reader.

Comment: The main point of a dict is to have data keyed on some unique identifier. If you need to artificially construct such an identifier, that's a good hint that you're using the wrong data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did return just the way I wanted. Just tweaked yours a small bit Happy Ahmad! HUGE THANKS!!! <3

```
def csv_to_list_with_dicts(csvfile):
    with open(csvfile, "r") as file:

        keys = file.readline().split(",")
        alteredKeys = []
        for eachKey in keys:
            counter = 0
            while(eachKey in alteredKeys):
                counter += 1
                eachKey = eachKey[:len(eachKey)-(0 if counter == 1 else 1)] + str(counter)
            alteredKeys.append(eachKey)

        list_of_issues = []
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',', skipinitialspace=True)
        for eachLine in reader:
            eachIssue = dict()
            columnIndex = 0
            for eachColumn in eachLine:
                if columnIndex < len(alteredKeys):
                    eachIssue[alteredKeys[columnIndex]] = eachColumn
                    columnIndex += 1
            list_of_issues.append(eachIssue)
    return list_of_issues
```

Answer (score 0):

It woujld be fairly easy to write code that will *automatically* generate unique keys for you by simply keeping track of those already seen and generating a unique name for any encountered that conflicted with one before it. Checking for that would be quick if those seen were kept in a `set` which features fast membership testing.

For example, assume this was in a CSV file named `non-unique.csv`:

```
User;ID;Comment;Comment;Comment
Jose;1138;something1;something2;something3
Gene;2907;abc;def;ghi
Guido;6450;jkl;mno;pqr
```

Code:

```
import csv


def csv_to_list_with_dicts(csv_filename):
    # Read the first row of the csv file.
    with open(csv_filename, encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';', skipinitialspace=True)
        names = next(reader)  # Header row.

    # Create list of unique fieldnames for the namee in the header row.
    seen = set()
    fieldnames = []
    for i, name in enumerate(names):
        if name in seen:
            name = f'_{i}'
        else:
            seen.add(name)
        fieldnames.append(name)

    # Read entire file and make each row a dictionary with keys based on the fieldnames.
    with open(csv_filename, encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=';', 
                                skipinitialspace=True)
        next(reader)  # Ignore header row.
        return list(reader)


results = csv_to_list_with_dicts('non-unique.csv')

from pprint import pprint
pprint(results, sort_dicts=False, width=120)
```

Results:

```
[{'User': 'Jose', 'ID': '1138', 'Comment': 'something1', '_3': 'something2', '_4': 'something3'},
 {'User': 'Gene', 'ID': '2907', 'Comment': 'abc', '_3': 'def', '_4': 'ghi'},
 {'User': 'Guido', 'ID': '6450', 'Comment': 'jkl', '_3': 'mno', '_4': 'pqr'}]
```

Comment: This is almost what im looking for, problem i see is when column header are like "User ID" with space the tuple key is just "_10" for example.

Comment: Yes, that's because `namedtuple`s requires names that are valid Python identifiers, but in dictionaries they only need to be unique in order to be keys. For that reason, I've changed the implementation so it is no longer based on them.

Answer (score 0):

In this solution, I use an alterKey list that changes any repeated key in the header by adding an index at its end. Then, I iterate on the other lines of the CSV file and make a dictionary from each one.

```
def csv_to_list_with_dicts(csvfile):
    with open(csvfile, "r") as file:    

        keys = file.readline().split(";")
        alteredKeys = []
        for eachKey in keys:
            counter = 0
            while(eachKey in alteredKeys):
                counter += 1
                eachKey = eachKey[:len(eachKey)-(0 if counter == 1 else 1)] + str(counter)
            alteredKeys.append(eachKey)

        list_of_issues = []
        for eachLine in file:
            eachIssue = dict()
            columnIndex = 0
            for eachColumn in eachLine.split(";")
                if columnIndex < len(alteredKeys):
                    eachIssue[alteredKeys[columnIndex]] = eachColumn
                columnIndex += 1
            list_of_issues.append(eachIssue)
    return list_of_issues
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: If I return alteredKeys all looks good (with correct headers) but if i Return  list_of_issues only the first column in the CSV is returned for each row.

[{'User': 'Joe}, {'User': 'Dan}, {'User': 'Smith'} .... ]

columnIndex +=1 on each will do it but since it's a CSV the splitline wont work all the way through if the comment is mulitiline i.e

Comment: @martineau You are right. I added some explanation to the solution.

Comment: @Sebastian I corrected the columnIndex incrementation, which I'm shocked why was missed before. I didn't understand whether the code works for you or not. Please explain more if you still have any problems with the solution.